# Exact sequence corresponding to $\bar{\phi} \in \operatorname{Ext}_{\Bbb Z}^1(\Bbb Z_9, \Bbb Z)$ without using Baer sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, exact-sequence, derived-functors

I found that $\operatorname{Ext}_{\Bbb Z}^1(\Bbb Z_9, \Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z_9$ by calculating it as the quotient of two $\operatorname{Hom}$-sets.

I am tasked with finding the (equivalence classes of) exact sequences corresponding to the elements in the group above.

I know two, the trivial one with middle module $\Bbb Z \oplus Z_9$, and the one with middle module $\Bbb Z$ with morphisms $\mu: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$, $\mu(n) = 9n$ and $\phi:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z_9$, $\phi(m) = \bar{m}$.

Since $9$ is not prime I don't know what I need to construct the remaining seven exact sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what a [pushout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)) is?  The construction you need is

$$
\begin{array}{llllllll}
0 & \to & \mathbb{Z} & \stackrel{\times 9}\to & \mathbb{Z} & \to & \mathbb{Z}/9 & \to & 0 \\
 & & \downarrow \phi & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \textrm{id} & & \\
0 & \to & \mathbb{Z} & \to & P & \to & \mathbb{Z}/9 & \to & 0
\end{array}
$$
where $P$ is the pushout of $\times 9$ and $\phi$, the homomorphism whose ext-class you are working with.

For abelian groups, the pushout can be identified with the quotient of the direct sum $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ by the subgroup generated by things of the form $(\phi(z), -9z)$: you can see immediately that $\phi=0$ gives you the trivial extension you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you! Assuming I have $\phi(1)=2$, what is the resulting quotient module? I feel like we would get $\Bbb Z_{18}$ but then the sequence would fail to be exact.

Comment: It won't be $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$, as you say: the pushout is the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ by the subgroup generated by $(2,-9)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ again (if you know about Smith Normal Form you can use that, or it's not hard by hand).  Remember that it's not just the groups in the short exact sequence that matter - the maps matter as well.

Comment: In the end, I only want $9$ equivalence classes of exact sequences. Which $\phi$ give equivalent exact sequences and how do I construct the morphism between two middle modules in such sequences?

Comment: Two $\phi$s give you equivalent classes iff they have the same cohomology class - you know what the classes look like, because you calculated the ext group. The middle map in the ses comes from the pushout construction: it's projection onto the second factor composed with the map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/9$ from the top row of my diagram.